# MVC AJAX ActionLink to post model data back to the controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, actionlink

I want to render a partial view on the same page so I used `ajax.actionlink` but the problem is based on the dropdown and text box selection. I need to send the form data back to the controller to populate a webgrid . All model values are going as null.

So for model data to go back to the controller I tried using `ajax.beginform` but that is rendering the partial view in another page instead of updating the div.

Can you please help what is the best solution to this?

Below is my code:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Add Role", "AddRoleList", "RegionalManagement", new {role=Model.TempUser.Roles,region=Model.TempUser.RegionID,fieldoffice=Model.TempUser.Fieldoffice}, new AjaxOptions
{
  HttpMethod = "POST",
  UpdateTargetId = "gridContent",
  InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
})
```

Controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult AddRoleList(string roles,int region,string fieldoffice)
{
  //Get List based on the filter criteria
  UserModel model = new UserModel();
  model.TempUserList = new List<TempUser>();
  model.TempUserList.Add(new TempUser()
  {
    Roles = roles,
    RegAbbr=region,
    Fieldoffice=fieldoffice
  });
  return PartialView("DisplayTemplates/_AddUserRolesGrid", model);
}
```

Comment: If its rendering the partial view on another page using `Ajax.BeginForm` then you have not included the relevant jquery files. (probably missing `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`)

Comment: I Have that referanced in my default layout file

Comment: Then you have possibly duplicated some other jquery files or have them in the wrong order.